# Convention of writing constraint sets

Tags: notation, convention

As I will write constraint sets very often, I would like to make sure that I respect the convention.

First, I would like to represent a set of constraints and their relation are conjunction. For instance, $[1 \leq i \leq 2, 1 \leq j \leq 2]$ means the set of all possible pairs of $(i,j)$: $\{(1,1); (1,2); (2,1); (2,2)\}$.

Do you think $[1 \leq i \leq 2, 1 \leq j \leq 2]$ or $\{1 \leq i \leq 2; 1 \leq j \leq 2\}$ is better?

Let's denote the above constraint set (a). Second, I want to say another constraint set "forall i, j satisfying (a), $x \leq i$ and $x \leq j$", which is actually $(-\infty, 1]$ for $x$.

Do you think $\forall i, j \in (a), [x \leq i, x \leq j]$ is the best way to formalize that?

Comment: In general your sets are written like that: $\{(i,j) : 1 \leq i \leq 2, 1 \leq j \leq 2 \}$, that is you describe the general element of your set then you give the constraints. More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_builder_notation

Comment: If you are talking about pairs $(i,j)$, then also use that notation in the description of the set: $A = \{(i,j) : 1 \leq i,j \leq 2\} = \{(1,1); (1,2); (2,1); (2,2)\}$. Then for the set of $x$-values you could write something like $X = \{x : \forall (i,j) \in A: x \leq i,j\} = (-\infty, 1]$.

Comment: Note that you can also save time and space by writing $\{(1,1); (1,2); (2,1); (2,2)\} = \{1,2\}^2$ which is also accepted notation.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you think $[1\le i\le 2,1 \le j\le 2]$ or $\{1\le i\le 2; 1\le j\le 2\}$ is better?

Both are bad. The first notation clashes with the popular [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) notation, which stands not for the set itself, but for its characteristic function. The second notation actually describes the set of *two* elements, in which one element is the inequality $1\le i\le 2$ and the other is the inequality $1\le j\le 2$. (Sets can contain not only numbers, but also formulas, words, and puppies -- possibly all together).

Standard ways to describe this set include $\{(i,j) : 1\le i\le 2, 1\le j\le 2\}$ and  $\{(i,j) \; |\; 1\le i\le 2, 1\le j\le 2\}$.

---

> Do you think $\forall i,j\in (a),[x\le i,x\le j]$ is the best way to formalize that?

Writing  "$i,j\in  (a)$" says that $i$ and $j$ are elements of (a). What you mean is  $(i,j)\in (a)$. But the role of $x$ (the fact that its possible values are to be collected into a set) remains somewhat unclear. I suggest either 
$$\{x : x\le i \text{ and }x\le j \text{ for all }(i,j)\in (a)\}$$
(plain English shouldn't be forgotten) or 
$$\bigcap_{(i,j)\in (a)}\{x : x\le i \text{ and }x\le j\}$$
Of course, there's a room for simplification with $x\le \min(i,j)$, but that's a different story.

---

(Answer partly based on comments by nik and TMM.)