# Notation for constraining a function over multiple ranges

Tags: notation, constraints, convention

I have a function f(x) = y, as well as a set of pairs of constraints in the form of ranges of x and ranges of y. In practice, x and y are both vectors.

I'm trying to express this more mathematically, but not having much luck.

As an example, the set of constraints on x = {(-2, -1), (+1, +2)}, and the corresponding set of constraints on y = {(-10, -5), (+5, +10)}, such that:

for -2 < x < -1: -10 < f(x) < -5 (the first (x, y) constraint pair)

for +1 < x < +2: +5 < f(x) < +10 (the second (x, y) constraint pair)

I'll admit I'm not a mathematician but I need to be able to express this in some work I'm doing. I've been googling and haven't managed to make a lot of sense of how to do it. Basic set builder notation I can grasp, but this is getting a little beyond me. This post seems quite related but I'm struggling a bit - [Convention of writing constraint sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114832/convention-of-writing-constraint-sets).

Is anyone more knowledgeable than myself able to make any suggestions?

Comment: I think what you've written is quite mathematical: "for $-2 < x < -1$: $-10 < f(x) < -5$...". Could you explain what you think is wrong with just writing this?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen - thank you Izaak. I'd like to be able to express it as the general form, rather than explicit line by line. So something that resembles {(x_min, x_max) ∈ Xconstraints, (y_min, y_max) ∈ Yconstraints : y_min < f(x_min < x < x_max) < y_max}. But I'm sure that notation is horribly wrong

Comment: Just write the same sentence again but with some variables in it! "For each pair of constraints $I = (x_{\text{min}}, x_{\text{max}})$ and $O = (y_{\text{min}}, y_{\text{max}})$, we have that whenever $x \in I$, necessarily $f(x) \in O$." It's kind of a common misconception that using a lot of symbols makes your writing "more mathematical".

Comment: Perhaps you could treat $f$ as a pair of functions $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ instead.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen - I like that suggestion, it does keep it more readable. And that would be accepted within the mathematical community?

Comment: $G(f)\subseteq \big( (-2,-1)\times (-10,-5)\big)\cup \big((1,2)\times (5,10)\big)$. That's where $G(f)$ is the [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function) of $f$.

Comment: @Ali - thank you Ali. I will do a bit of reading on the symbols and the link you provided